# Office interop Chart autoscaling

Tags: c#, graph, charts, interop, autoscaling

For generate one graph in my word interop document I use the method below:

```
    public static void AddSimpleChart(Document WordDoc, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp, string[,] data)
    {

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape oShape;
        object oClassType = "MSGraph.Chart.8";
        object oEndOfDoc4 = "\\endofdoc";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wrdRng = WordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc4).Range;
        oShape = wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ref oClassType, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


        //Demonstrate use of late bound oChart and oChartApp objects to   
        //manipulate the chart object with MSGraph.   
        object oChart;
        object oChartApp;
        oChart = oShape.OLEFormat.Object;

        oChartApp = oChart.GetType().InvokeMember("Application", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oChart, null);

        //Change the chart type to Line.   
        object[] Parameters = new Object[1];
        Parameters[0] = 1; //xlLine = 4   
        oChart.GetType().InvokeMember("ChartType", BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            null, oChart, Parameters);



        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart objChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart)oShape.OLEFormat.Object;

        objChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;

        DataSheet dataSheet;
        dataSheet = objChart.Application.DataSheet;
        int rownum = data.GetLength(0);
        int columnnum = data.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= rownum; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= columnnum; j++)
            {
                dataSheet.Cells[i, j] = data[i - 1, j - 1];

            }

        objChart.Application.Update();
        oChartApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Update",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oChartApp, null);
        oChartApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Quit",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oChartApp, null);


        oShape.Width = WordApp.InchesToPoints(6.25f);
        oShape.Height = WordApp.InchesToPoints(3.57f);
        wrdRng = WordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc4).Range;
        wrdRng.InsertParagraphAfter(); 

    }
```

But the rendered graph was to small.

Anyone know how to set the autoscaling option in my method.

When I set this property: objChart.AutoScaling = true I get an exception.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the exception's message?

Comment: Hi,
Here is the exception message:

  Message=Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))
  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape.get_Chart()

Thk!

Comment: I think AutoScaling is for 3d charts. Also by 'too small' you mean the height and width of the shape decreased or inner chart element reduced?

Comment: I mean the inner chart element reduced. But when I open the word document and double click to the chart, it get the right size when i leave the chart zone ... strange ...